# Crear tabla de 'strings' e identificarlos a índices concretos

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Soy un beginner de Python que está empezando a familiarizarse con la libreria pymc.
Mi duda es la siguiente:
Creé una Distribución Discreta Uniforme para modelar la probabilidad de encontrar ciertos nombres dentro de una base de datos:

```
nombres_clientes = pm.Geometric('nombres_clientes', p=0.02685)
```

Al generar variable aleatorias, obviamente me devuelve un array con números enteros(en este caso un array de 10 int):

```
nombres_clientes = nombres_clientes.random(size=10)
```

La historia de este post es que quiero relacionar cada variable int a un nombre concreto a traves de una tabla, como si cada nombre tuviese un identificador, pero no sé como implementarla en el código.

**Lo que quiero es que a la salida al hacer un print(nombre_clientes) en vez de salirme por pantalla un array [ 54 2 45 75 22 19 16 34 67 88] me salga [ Jose Maria Carmen Alejandro Davinia Eduardo Carlos Fátima Marc Mireia].**

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
def identificar_nombres(nc = numeros_identificativos):
    for i in range (0, 9): #en este caso 9 porque arriba estamos sacando 10 num aleatorios
        if nc[i] == '1':
            return 'ANTONIO' 
        elif nc[i] == '2':
            return 'MARIA CARMEN'
        else: return nc[i] # proceso repetidas veces con todos los nombres del dataset de nombres

nombres = identificar_nombres(numeros_identificativos)
```

pero sin resultado.

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste hacer?

Comment: Intenté usar esta solución pero no me daba resultado: def identificar_nombres(nc = numeros_identificativos):
    for i in range (0, 9): #en este caso 9 porque arriba estamos sacando 10 num aleatorios
        if nc[i] == '1':
            return 'ANTONIO'
        elif nc[i] == '2':
            return 'MARIA CARMEN'
        else:
            return nc[i]
                # proceso repetidas veces con todos los nombres del dataset de nombres             nombres = identificar_nombres(numeros_identificativos)

Comment: Holaa Eduardo, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Cualquier información relevante y en especial el código debes agregarlo en la pregunta. Para ello usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/331178/edit) que hay debajo de la misma y añade todo lo que quieras en ella. Los comentarios están muy limitados en cuanto a caracteres y además se pierde el formato del código. Un saludo.